# Windows 10 Build 1903 Guest OS on 2012 Hyper-V Host is freezing

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10-v1903

I created a Guest machine windows 10 Build 1903 on 2012 R2 Host Hyper-V. It works ok at the beginning and then becomes unresponsive. I can't remote, From the host server, client windows shows black screen. I have to foree shutdown the guest to make it work again. No blue screen. Tried removing hyper-v features, updating the server to the latest patches, nothing helped. I don't have the same problem with 1809 Builds.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Kuby - In order to properly answer this question.  We must know specifics about each installation.  What cumlative updates do you have installed on the Windows 10 VM?  What is the last patch you installed on the Windows Server 2012 R2?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, executing `Restart-Service 'HV Host Service'` in a PowerShell Admin prompt seems to be making the VMs responsive again.